# Navigation Drawer and android data binding

Tags: java, android, data-binding, navigation-drawer, android-databinding

Sorry for my English. I need to process a button click with Android Data Binding. I include in content_main.xml data binding.

```
    <data>
            <variable
                name="temp"
                type="skubyev.anton.navigationdrawer.DataBindingClass.MainActivityData" />
            <variable
                name="presenter"
                type="skubyev.anton.navigationdrawer.DataBindingClass.MainActivityPresenter"/>
        </data>
....
     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onShowData(temp)}"
```

But MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ContentMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_main);

        MainActivityPresenter mainActivityPresenter = new MainActivityPresenter(this);
        MainActivityData mainActivityData = new MainActivityData("Иди нахуй");
        binding.setTemp(mainActivityData);
        binding.setPresenter(mainActivityPresenter);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
....

 @Override
    public void showData(MainActivityData mainActivityData) {
        String textForRecognition = mainActivityData.getTextForRecognition();
        Toast.makeText(this, textForRecognition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I want the function **showData** run then i click on FloatingActionButton in content_main. But showData - function in class MainActivity. And therefore as I understand it is not called when you click on the button located on the **content_main.xml**. What do i do? Create a separate class ContentActivity.java whith function showData.

I just want to MainActivity.java was responsible for processing the click on content_main. How to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Activity add this code for databinding like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    MainViewmodel mainViewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewmodel.class);
    activityMainBinding.setHandlers(handlers);
    activityMainBinding.setViewmodel(mainViewmodel);



    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("HOME");

    DrawerLayout drawer = activityMainBinding.drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = activityMainBinding.navView;
    NavHeaderMainBinding navHeaderMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.nav_header_main, activityMainBinding.navView, true);
    navHeaderMainBinding.navEmail.setText(session.getFacilityEmail());
    navHeaderMainBinding.navName.setText(session.getFacilityname());
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



}
```

in nav_hader_main.xml you have to be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="navigationheader"
        type="com.nudge.gurukul.view.activities.MainActivity" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/app_logo_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_email"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this should as per you excepted and you can bind the text and image to navigation drawer

Comment: what is the use of databinding if u are using  Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);